# Creating a dynamic text field that changes content depending on select list choice?

Tags: php, sql, dynamic

Me and my colleague are in the process of starting up our own company that handles exam results and school data. I am currently in the process of setting up the webpage (I am completely new with PHP and Dreamweaver CC) where the end-user can access and edit the database in the extent that they need to.

But I shall get to the point of my problem. At the moment I am trying to build a data edit page where all relevant data is shown once the user has logged in (In this case it's an admin-kind of person, so he/she needs to see which teacher teaches which classes). On this page I want to build a drop-down list of all the possible Classes (done this with the recordset, sorted alphabetically and working) and linking to that, a dynamic text field that changes value depending on the option picked in the select list.

Example:

There are four classes, and four corresponding teachers as followed:

### Class - Teacher

English - Bob

Spanish - Juan

Math - Jenny

Geography - William

What I'm basically after is that if you choose the Class 'English' in the drop-down select list, the text field should display 'Bob' (and similarly for all the other classes). So far I've not managed to work out how to do that in Dreamweaver CC.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that both the class names and the corresponding teachers are a result from the query I've set up in a recordset - so instead of having to make the link myself I have to display that link (it does so for the very first school name in the dropdown list, but I think that's because of the nature of the query)

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: There's several ways to do this, but I'd have an event handler attached to the menu item, which updates the correct DOM element with the new name. Whilst you could use AJAX (i.e. a background fetch) it seems that the amount of data you have here would make it amenable to rendering your names table in a JavaScript array, and using it as a lookup table when the event triggers. You will need to learn some JavaScript (and maybe a library like jQuery to make it easier).

Comment: (This question, as interesting as it is, is rather too broad for here. It would be best to give it a go, and to ask more directed questions if you get stuck).

Comment: Use jquery with ajax to get the data from database using php - http://www.bennadel.com/resources/presentations/jquery/demo21/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP is a server side language; not a client side one. You're gonna need JS and not PHP for this task. Try this

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('.teacher').change(function(){
      var teacher = $(this).val();  
      $('#text').val(teacher);
   });
</script>

<?php
    //If all of the info for the classes is stored in MySQL, then do this
    //I'm not sure how your DB is structured, but you should get the idea here
    //Query the DB for all of the teachers and the subjects they teach
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password", "database");
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM classes");
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    $i = 0;

   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      $teacher[$i] = $row['teacher'];
      $subject[$i] = $row['subject'];

      $i++;
   }
?>
<select class="teacher">
<?php
    //Loop thru and for each row, echo out an option tag
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) {
        echo "<option value='".$teacher[$i]."'>".$subject[$i]."</option>";
    }
?>
</select>

<input type="text" id="text" value="" />
```

Comment: Good effort Lance, even if I'd take the view that for the OP to _really_ learn, they need to be encouraged to write at least some of it for themselves. +1

Comment: I forgot to mention that the values for both the Class and the Teacher come from a recordset linked to our database - so it's all dynamic. Is there a way for the script to work this out automatically, or will I have to enter all the values by hand? (I think that will get quite time consuming for some of our entries)

Comment: Yes, there certainly is. Hold on a sec and wait for my updated answer

Comment: Done! Check my new answer

Comment: Many thanks for that Lance, I shall implement it later and let you know if it works! :)

Comment: Sure. Please click on the green checkmark next to my answer and/or upvote it you feel that it has helped you at all. Let me know if you have any more questions or concerns too!

Comment: Lance, the text field does not actually put any data out - have I missed something really obvious?

Comment: Works just fine for me. Check this fiddle out http://jsfiddle.net/lnlance09/AEccR/